# Concatenating vectors and matrices as columns

Tags: numpy

I'm currently doing something like:

```
In [75]: a = np.arange(7)

In [76]: b = np.arange(3 * 7).reshape([3, 7])

In [77]: np.stack([a, *b], axis=1)
Out[77]:
array([[ 0,  0,  7, 14],
       [ 1,  1,  8, 15],
       [ 2,  2,  9, 16],
       [ 3,  3, 10, 17],
       [ 4,  4, 11, 18],
       [ 5,  5, 12, 19],
       [ 6,  6, 13, 20]])
```

Is there a better alternative to `np.stack` where I wouldn't need to unpack `b`? I'm wondering what's the most readable way.

Comment: The basic way of doing this is `np.concatenate((a[:,None], b.T), axis=1)`.  Both `stack` and `column_stack` manipulate the inputs which are then passed to `concatenate`.  `*stack` functions are convenient, but it's a good idea to understand shapes well enough to use `concatenate` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose `b` and then use [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
np.column_stack((a, b.T))
#array([[ 0,  0,  7, 14],
#       [ 1,  1,  8, 15],
#       [ 2,  2,  9, 16],
#       [ 3,  3, 10, 17],
#       [ 4,  4, 11, 18],
#       [ 5,  5, 12, 19],
#       [ 6,  6, 13, 20]])
```